# Why is the precision accurate when Decimal() takes in a string instead of float? in Python

Tags: python, python-decimal

Why are these values different and how does it differ from each other?

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal('0.1') + Decimal('0.1') + Decimal('0.1') - Decimal('0.3')
Decimal('0.0')

>>> Decimal(0.1) + Decimal(0.1) + Decimal(0.1) - Decimal(0.3)
Decimal('2.775557561565156540423631668E-17')
```

Comment: Because *a `float` is inherently imprecise*. That is *why `decimal.Decimal` exists in the first place*

Comment: (won't reopen without discussion) I disagree this is a duplicate. The question is why is the precision accurate when `Decimal()` takes in a string

Comment: Have you tried to do `Decimal("0.1") == 0.1` and `Decimal(0.1) == 0.1`?

Comment: The precision is already lost when you represent a number with a floating point, and passing an imprecise number to the `Decimal` constructor will not recover the lost precision.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quoted from Decimal module source code which explains pretty good, if the input is float, the module internally calls the class method "Decimal.from_float()":

> Note that Decimal.from_float(0.1) is not the same as Decimal('0.1').
>           Since 0.1 is not exactly representable in binary floating point, the
>           value is stored as the nearest representable value which is
>           0x1.999999999999ap-4.  The exact equivalent of the value in decimal
>           is 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass `'0.1'` as string, the decimal is converted to a float, without losing precision, but it loses precision when you pass the float directly as `0.1`, as you can see below

```
>>> Decimal(0.1)
Decimal('0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625')
>>> Decimal('0.1')
Decimal('0.1')
```

This then leads to all sort of wierd results

```
>>> Decimal(0.3) - Decimal(0.1) + Decimal(0.1) + Decimal(0.1)
Decimal('0.3999999999999999944488848768')
```